# Check if Screen Component is being presented Modally or is within TabNavigator in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

Using React Native & [react-native-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation/) I have navigation set up as per the below;

```
const HomeLayout = () => {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="Search"
        component={SearchScreen}
        options={{
          presentation: "fullScreenModal",
        }}
      />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
};

const TabLayout = () => {
  return (
    <Tabs.Navigator>
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="HomeLayout"
        component={HomeLayout}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="Search"
        component={SearchScreen}
      />
    </Tabs.Navigator>
  );
};
```

I want to check if my SearchScreen is being presented in my HomeLayout modally or it is within my Tabs Navigator, depending on this I need to do some UI customisations.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking the parent navigator I felt the easiest way was to add an initial param of modal to true or false. Based on this change the UI.

```
<Tabs.Screen
    name="Search"
    component={SearchScreen}
    initialParams={{ modal: false }}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color }) => (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          name={focused ? "text-box-search" : "text-box-search-outline"}
          size={25}
          color={color}
        />
      ),
    }}
  />
```